# creation of rpm with a jar file through maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar, rpm

I am trying to create a rpm through maven plugin. Rpm consists of jar file and other some scripts. I can create a jar file as a separate maven build and rpm as separate build. 
Is it possible to create a an rpm, which includes the jar files. ie) my expectation is that it should compile the java source code and create a jar file out of it and then create an rpm through maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to use the [rpm-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) which can help here.

Comment: @Thanks khmarbaise. I can generate the rpm's individually. The problem is i am having an jar files which includes some functionalities. First i have to convert it to a jar file ie)compile all the source files and generate jar and then create an rpm using the maven bundle rpm-maven-plugin. Second i need to generate rpm with the jar file

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do by adding the jar dependency in rpm package which build by rpm-maven-plugin.

```
<mapping>
<directory>Your directory path</directory>
<filemode>0755</filemode>
<sources>
   <source>
   <location>src/rpm/data</location>
   </source>
 </sources>
 <dependency>
  <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
   <includes>
      <include>Your jar with version</includes>
   </includes>
 </dependency>
 </mapping>
```